# Monotonic sequences and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

Are these two following statements correct?

1. A sequence is convergent if and only if all of its subsequences are convergent.
2. A sequence is monotonic if and only if all of its subsequences are monotonic.

Comment: Yes. -----------

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$. If there is some subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of $(x_{n})$ such that $(x_{n_{k}})$ diverges, then for every $l \in \Bbb{R}$ there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ and infinitely many $k$ such that $|x_{n_{k}} - l| \geq \varepsilon$;  this shows that $(x_{n})$ diverges. Conversely, if $(x_{n})$ diverges, then for every $l \in \Bbb{R}$ there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ and infinitely many $n$ such that $|x_{n}-l| \geq \varepsilon$; hence some subsequence of $(x_{n})$ diverges.

You should try to do the second statement, which is way more straightforward.